# How to set up a NSComboBox using prepare for segue or init?

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift3

I am really struggling to pass the contents of one array from a view controller to another to set up the contents of a nscombobox. I have tried everything I can think of, prepare for segue, init; but nothing seems to work. 
the program flow is as follows: the user enter a number into a text field and based on it an array with the size of the number is created. Once the user presses a button the next VC appears that has a combo box and inside that combo box those numbers need to appear. All my attempts result in an empty array being passed. Could someone please take a bit of time and help me out. Im sure I'm doing a silly mistake but cannot figure out what.
Code listing below:
Class that take the user input. At this stage I'm trying to pass the contents of the array in the next class as I gave up on prepare for segue because that one crashes because of nil error. Please note that prepare for segue is uncommented in the code listing just for formatting purposes here. Im my program it is commented out as I am using perform segue at the moment.
Any solution would be nice please. Thank you.

```
import Cocoa

class SetNumberOfFloorsVC: NSViewController {

    //MARK: - Properties

    @IBOutlet internal weak var declaredNumber: NSTextField!

    internal var declaredFloorsArray = [String]()    

    private var floorValue: Int {
        get {
            return Int(declaredNumber.stringValue)!
        }
    }

    //MARK: - Actions

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction private func setNumberOfFloors(_ sender: NSButton) {
        if declaredNumber.stringValue.isEmpty {
            let screenAlert = NSAlert.init()
            screenAlert.messageText = "Please specify the number of floors!"
            screenAlert.addButton(withTitle: "Got it!")
            screenAlert.runModal()

        } else if floorValue == 0 || floorValue < 0 {
            let screenAlert = NSAlert.init()
            screenAlert.messageText = "Please input a correct number of floors!"
            screenAlert.addButton(withTitle: "Got it!")
            screenAlert.runModal()
        } else {
            for i in 0...floorValue - 1 {
                declaredFloorsArray.append(String(i))
            }
            print("\(declaredFloorsArray)")
            let declareNumberOfRoomsVC = SetNumberOfRoomsForFloorVC(boxData: declaredFloorsArray)
            declareNumberOfRoomsVC.boxData = declaredFloorsArray
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "set number of rooms", sender: self)
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       if segue.identifier == "set number of rooms" {
            if let addRoomsVC = segue.destinationController as? SetNumberOfRoomsForFloorVC {
                addRoomsVC.floorBox.addItems(withObjectValues: declaredFloorsArray)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the class for the next VC with the combo box:

```
import Cocoa

class SetNumberOfRoomsForFloorVC: NSViewController, NSComboBoxDelegate, NSComboBoxDataSource {

    //MARK: - Properties

    @IBOutlet internal weak var floorBox: NSComboBox!

    @IBOutlet private weak var numberOfRoomsTxtField: NSTextField!

    internal var boxData = [String]()

    //MARK: - Init

    convenience init(boxData: [String]) {
        self.init()
        self.boxData = boxData
    }

    //MARK: - Actions

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        floorBox.usesDataSource = true
        floorBox.dataSource = self
        floorBox.delegate = self
        print("\(boxData)")
    }

    @IBAction private func setRoomsForFloor(_ sender: NSButton) {

    }

    //MARK: - Delegates

    func numberOfItems(in comboBox: NSComboBox) -> Int {
        return boxData.count
    }
    func comboBox(_ comboBox: NSComboBox, objectValueForItemAt index: Int) -> Any? {
        return boxData[index]
    } 
}
```

Comment: internal var boxData = [String]()?  floorBox.usesDataSource = true?  All you have to do is just to pass an array to the combo guy.

Answer (score 0):

First you should remove the following code.

```
let declareNumberOfRoomsVC = SetNumberOfRoomsForFloorVC(boxData: declaredFloorsArray)
declareNumberOfRoomsVC.boxData = declaredFloorsArray
```

I assume you think that the viewController you created here is passed to `prepareForSegue`. However the storyboard instantiates a new viewController for you.

After that you need to set your `declaredFloorsArray` as the the boxData of the new viewController in `prepareForSegue` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have solved the problem by using the represented object and passing values thorough it. I found about it being the most convenient way by accident.